# mui-x/charts error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: typescript, bar-chart, mui-x-charts

I am facing a problem on my @mui-x/charts library. I have a React Typescript project and when I try to plot the StackedBarChart example from https://mui.com/x/react-charts/bar-demo/ , I get this error on my screen:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

and when I check the terminal, it shows:

```
error - /myproject/node_modules/@mui/x-charts/esm/index.js:1
export * from './constants';
```

My package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
        "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
        "@mui/system": "^5.14.11",
        "@mui/x-charts": "^6.0.0-alpha.13",
        "canvas": "^2.11.2",
        "next": "12.2.3",
        "next-translate": "^1.5.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
}
```

I tried with nodejs 16 and nodejs 18, but no one solves, Does anybody has a clue?

Comment: Do you have `type: module` in package.jsobn

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I have the same issue myself (the error I am getting is on the line "export { BarPlot } from './BarPlot';"), did you find a resolution?  I am using from a NextJS project

Comment: i didnt, i think is related to the alpha project of them..

Comment: Are you using NextJS framework? I had the same issue with the library, but solved it by adding `transpilePackages: ['@mui/x-charts']` to my `next.config.js` file. https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#module-transpilation

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue. The suggestion by Adrian worked for me. I solved it by adding the below to my `next.config.js` file and rebuilt

`transpilePackages: ['@mui/x-charts']`

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#module-transpilation

Comment: i am sorry, on my next 12, it didnt work, i got;
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
"params": {
  "additionalProperty": "transpilePackages"
},
"message": "must NOT have additional properties"

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error during jest testing only, when leveraging BarChart. I had no luck with transform, ignoreTransforms, or transpile. I am on React 18, Node 18, Typescript 4.6.4, with a customized react-scripts.

I resolved it by updating my `setupTests.ts`:

```
jest.mock("@mui/x-charts", () => ({ 
  BarChart: jest.fn().mockImplementation(({ children }) => children)
}));
```